# urxvt add padding (distance between text and border)

Tags: urxvt

Is it possible to increase the space between text and border in urxvt, and if so, how? I can't find any resources on it online.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are looking for the `internalBorder` value:

```
URxvt.internalBorder:  4
```

From `man urxvt`:

> internalBorder: number
>      Internal border of number pixels. This resource is limited to 100; 
>      option -b.